# How to rename multiple columns in this SQL snippet?

Tags: mysql, sql

> Write a query below that retrieves the departure harbour, the
>   departure date, the amount of voyages (rows) as column n, the minimum
>   and maximum tonnage in each group (min_t / max_t) from the voyages
>   table. Group by departure harbour and departure date. Filter out rows
>   where departure harbour is NULL or equal to Batavia. Filter the groups
>   to have at least two voyages in them.

I am close, but I don't get what they mean with `in each group (min_t / max_t)`

What do I need to do there? This is the table I should be getting...

```
#   departure_harbour   departure_date  n   min_t   max_t
1   Batavia               1768          2   136      1150
```

And this is what I get with my query....

```
#   departure_harbour   departure_date  MIN(tonnage)    MAX(tonnage)    n
1   NULL                    1793            488             890         3
```

I have this:

```
SELECT departure_harbour, 
       departure_date, 
       MIN(tonnage), 
       MAX(tonnage), 
       COUNT() AS n 
FROM   voyages 
GROUP BY departure_harbour, 
         departure_date 
HAVING   departure_harbour IS NULL 
    OR   departure_harbour = "Batavia"
```

When I state min_t and max_t after `AS`, it just gives me errors. I don't know how to do this. Beside that: how can I change the order of the columns as shown in the tables?

Comment: What error message did you get?  How *exactly* did you try aliasing the columns?

Comment: Well, I tried (..) COUNT() AS n, max_t, min_t, but this gave me the error: Query failed: no such column.

Comment: What's up with is null in the having for departure_harbour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I come up with when I read the assignment.

I used coalesce to convert null departure harbours to Batavia since we need to exclude all nulls and Batavia.

```
SELECT departure_harbour
     , departure_date
     , count(1) n
     , min (tonnage) min_t
     , max(tonnage) max_t
FROM voyages
WHERE coalesce(departure_harbour,'Batavia') <> 'Batavia'
GROUP BY  departure_harbour
        , departure_date
HAVING count(1)>1
```

Comment: I totally forgot I can use coalesce! It's so logical. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should filter **out** harbors with `NULL` and Batavia, you are only retrieving `NULL` and Ceylon. You should fix your having clause.
2. min_t and max_t are names you should give to aggregation columns, such as `MIN(tonnage) as min_t`.
3. You did not filter groups to have at least to voyages. You need to add a condition to having clause for that.

Apart from these your effort seems ok.

Comment: Okay, so min_t and max_t are given how? Comma separated after the AS I used or somewhere else? What does filtering OUT exactly mean?

Comment: @Siyah you should rename each column seperately. `...min(tonnage) as min_t, max(tonnage) as max_t...` And filtering out is excluding the rows that satisfy the condition. Since `HAVING`selects rows based on a condition, your having clauses should have the opposite condition.